# Read a CSV file and list of folders and then compare in VB

Tags: vba, vbscript

What I am trying to achieve is I currently have a (main) folder filled with many Sub-folders and these sometimes get drag & dropped into another Sub-folder by accident.

I have an CSV file containing all the names of the current (main) folder list as it should stand and I want to check this against the current version of Sub-folders found in the (main) folder and output a message box with the results of matching files and missing files.

This is the code I have got so far although I am unsure how to check the list of      folders against the CSV file.

Read data from an CSV file.

```
'Holds Data from CSV file
Dim arrValue As String()
'create a new TextFieldParser and opens the file
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox (Personal)\IT\jobs.csv")

'Define the TextField type and delimiter
MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = MyReader.ReadFields()
            If arrValue Is Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve arrValue(0)
                arrValue(0) = arrCurrentRow(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve arrValue(arrValue.Length)
                arrValue((arrValue.Length - 1)) = arrCurrentRow(0)
            End If
End While
```

Read list of folders

```
    'check against the Clients folder
    Set w = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    w.Popup ShowFolders("C:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox (Innovation PS)\Clients")
    Function ShowFolders(folderName)

    'Setting Variables
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s

    'holds folder name
    s = ""

    'Obtain folder Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderName)

    'Obtain SubFolders collection within folder
    Set fc = f.SubFolders

    'Examine each item in the collection
    For Each f1 in fc
    s = s & f1.name
    s = s & (Chr(13) & Chr(10)) ' Chr(13) & Chr(10) = Carriage return–linefeed combination
    Next
    ShowFolders = s
    End Function
    'See if it matches the .CSV file
```

Thank you in advance. (Also if you could include comments it would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Run this script to get a base line, it wil create a spreadsheet of the folders files and properties,  Then runt it again copy the sheet in to the baseline work bbok and do a vlookup.  You could also use this as a base line to create a csv and compare the it that way.  Not exactly waht you are looking for but it is a workable solution

```
  Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, Forappending = 8   
 'Option Explicit
 'DIM Objects


 'Dim variabbles
 Dim folderspec
 'Dim 

 DIM arrBlk(3) 
 DIM arrFLN(3) 
 DIM arrInfo(3)
 Set objXL = Wscript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



 folderspec = InputBox("Please enter the path", "FileList", " ") 
            If folderspec  = ""  Then 
              ' if cancel is selected quit the program
               wscript.quit
            ElseIf  folderspec  = " "  Then
               ' if nothing is entered give a warning message ang quit the program  
                 msgbox "No Directory has been seleted " & vbCrLf 
                  wscript.quit
            End If

 intRow = 2
 buildsheet() 'Build the XLS spreadsheet

 'folderspec ="C:\_epas_5.0\Web_Server\ASP"
 'folderspec ="C:\_epas_5.0\Web_Server\COM+ Source"

 strFldrCmp = folderspec
 Set root = ofso.GetFolder(folderspec)

 ShowFileList(root)
 For Each oFolder in root.subfolders
   walkfolder oFolder
 Next

 Sub walkfolder(f)
  ShowFileList(f)
   For Each sf in f.subfolders
       walkfolder sf
   Next
 End Sub

 Function ShowFileList(folderspec)
    Dim oFolder
    Dim oFiles
    Dim oFile

    Set oFolder = ofso.GetFolder(folderspec)
   ' Wscript.echo oFolder.name
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
   ' If  IsEmpty(oFiles) Then Wscript.echo oFolder.name
 'i = 0   
   For Each oFile in oFiles
    i = 1 + i
    'If i < 1 Then
    'Wscript.echo oFolder.name,i
 'End If
   Next 
   If i < 1 Then 

    Wscript.echo  oFolder.name & " Null"
    ReDim arrB(3)
    'strPath = Replace(oFolder.path,strFldrCmp,"", 1 ,1 ,vbTextCompare)
        arrB(0) = "\" & Trim(oFolder.Name) 'oFolder.path
        arrB(1) = ""
        arrB(2) =  ""
        arrB(3) = ""
        AddLineToXLS(arrB)
   End If     

    For Each oFile in oFiles
      ReDim arrB(3)
      srtfldr = oFolder.path
     ' MsgBox srtfldr& " " & strFldrCmp
 'strPath = Replace(srtfldr,strFldrCmp,"", 1 ,1 ,vbTextCompare)
 strPath = Replace(oFolder.path,strFldrCmp,"", 1 ,1 ,vbTextCompare)
 'strPath = Replace("C:\_5Test\Web_Server\ASP\app\admin","C:\_5Test\Web_Server\ASP","",,,vbTestCompare)
        arrB(0) = Trim(strPath) 'oFolder.path
        arrB(1) = Trim(oFile.name)
        arrB(2) =  Trim(oFile.Size)
        arrB(3) = Trim(oFile.DateLastModified)
           If   LCase(ofso.GetExtensionName(oFile)) <> "scc" Then 'skip VSS .scc files
             AddLineToXLS(arrB)
           End If
    Next
 End Function



 Function buildsheet
  intRow = 1
       objXL.Visible = True
       objXL.WorkBooks.Add

     '** Set Row Height
          objXL.Rows(1).RowHeight = 17

     '** Set Column widths
          objXL.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 40.14
          objXL.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 33.14
          objXL.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 15
          objXL.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 23
          objXL.Columns(5).ColumnWidth = 23
          objXL.Columns(6).ColumnWidth = 23


     '** Set Cell Format for Column Titles ***
          objXL.Range("A1:F1").Select
             objXL.Selection.Font.Bold = True
            ' objXL.Selection.Font.Size = 8
             objXL.Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
             objXL.Selection.Interior.Pattern = 1      'xlSolid
             objXL.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 1
             objXL.Selection.WrapText = True
          objXL.Columns("A:T").Select
          objXL.Columns.Font.Size = 8
             objXL.Selection.HorizontalAlignment = 1     'xlCenter
          objXL.Columns("C:C").Select
             objXL.Selection.NumberFormat = "#,###0"
          objXL.Columns("D:D").Select
             objXL.Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM"

     '*** Set Column Titles ***
       Dim arrA(3)
         arrA(0)= "File Path"
         arrA(1) = "File Name"
         arrA(2) = "Size(bytes)"
         arrA(3) = "Modified Date/Time"


         AddLineToXLS(arrA)

 End Function

 Function AddLineToXLS(r)' Writes a line to the spreadsheet  recieves an array as input

      objXL.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = r(0)
      objXL.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = r(1)
      objXL.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = r(2)
      objXL.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = r(3)
     ' MsgBox r(3)
     'objXL.Cells(intRow, 5).Value = r(4)
     'objXL.Cells(intRow, 6).Value = r(5)
    ' objXL.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = r(3)

      intRow = intRow + 1
      objXL.Cells(1, 1).Select

 End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not looking to go through all the subfolders just the top level of folders.
There are well over 10,000 folders and files all together within these 100 top level folders